# Integer expression expected

Tags: bash

I want to read my files line by line every 5 seconds. This time I just tried one-line bash command to do this.
And bash command is:

```
let X=1;while [ $X -lt 20 ];do cat XXX.file |head -$X|tail -1;X=$X+1;sleep 5;done
```

However I got the error like:

```
-bash: [: 1+1: integer expression expected
```

What's the problem?
btw, why can't we do $X < 20? (Instead we have to do -lt, less than?)

thx

Comment: And this doesn't address your question at all, but have you considered using the `read` operator, rather than that cat-head-tail thing?  It would be simpler and *much* less IO-intensive.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your assignment `X=$X+1` doesn't perform arithmetic. If `$X` is 1, it sets it to the string `"1+1"`.  Change `X=$X+1` to `let X=X+1` or `let X++`.

As for the use of `-lt` rather than `<`, that's just part of the syntax of `[` (i.e., the `test` command).  It uses `=` and `!=` for *string* equality and inequality `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, and `-ge` for numbers.  As @Malvolio points out, the use of `<` would be inconvenient, since it's the input redirection operator.

(The `test` / `[` command that's built into the bash shell does accept `<` and `>`, but not `<=` or `>=`, for strings. But the `<` or `>` character has to be quoted to avoid interpretation as an I/O redirection operator.)

Or consider using the equivalent `(( expr ))` construct rather than the `let` command. For example, `let X++` can be written as `((X++))`. At least bash, ksh, and zsh support this, though sh likely doesn't. I haven't checked the respective documentation, but I presume the shells' developers would want to make them compatible.

Answer (score 1):

*I* would use

```
X=`expr $X + 1`
```

but that's just me.  And you cannot say $X < 20 because < is the input-redirect operator.

Comment: Is "because" sufficient answer?  The shell's parser is not very sophisticated.  It was written sometime around 1970.   Do you remember 1970?  I don't and I'm older than you.  There have been a lot of updates to shell, of course, but nobody wants to break backward-compatibility.

Comment: -> `expr` is a program and it expects operands and operators to be separate command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The sum `X=$X+1` should be `X=$(expr $X + 1 )`.

You can also use `<` for the comparison, but you have to write `(("$X" < "20"))` with the double parenthesis instead of `[ $X -lt 20 ]`.